# HTK 3.4.1 installation error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, htk

I tried almost every solutions which written on google but still is not working.

Here after typed ./configure :

```
    configure: creating ./config.status
    config.status: creating HTKLib/Makefile
    config.status: WARNING:  HTKLib/Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
    config.status: creating HTKTools/Makefile
    config.status: WARNING:  HTKTools/Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
    config.status: creating HLMLib/Makefile
    config.status: WARNING:  HLMLib/Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
    config.status: creating HLMTools/Makefile
    config.status: WARNING:  HLMTools/Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
    config.status: creating HTKLVRec/Makefile
    config.status: WARNING:  HTKLVRec/Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
    config.status: creating Makefile
    config.status: WARNING:  Makefile.in seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting

**************************************************

HTK is now ready to be built.

Type "make all" to build the HTK libraries
and tools.

Then "make install" to install them.

The tools will be installed in /usr/local/bin

Build notes: Language Modelling tools will be
built. HDecode will not be built. You can build
it manually later by running 'make hdecode
install-hdecode'
```

It seems like something going wrong at configuration part.

```
(cd HTKTools && make all) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hmtsk/voxforge/bin/htk/HTKTools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hmtsk/voxforge/bin/htk/HTKTools'
(cd HLMTools && make all) \
      || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/hmtsk/voxforge/bin/htk/HLMTools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hmtsk/voxforge/bin/htk/HLMTools'
```

I already tried:

- sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
- sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
- ./configure --disable-hslab --disable-hlmtools
- sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386
- sudo gedit configure.ac then remove "-m32" in the file.

I need your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your error is. You can ignore the warnings about -datarootdir, I get those too, but make completes correctly. Your output looks correct.

Check the contents of your directories HTKTools and HLMTools. See if any binaries have been created. You can test whether they work or not by running something like:

```
./HLMTools/LMerge

USAGE: LMerge [options] wordList inModel outModel

 Option                                       Default

 -f s    set output LM format to s            BIN
 -i f s  interpolate with model s, weight f   off
 -n n    produce n-gram model                 max
 -A      Print command line arguments         off
 -C cf   Set config file to cf                default
 -D      Display configuration variables      off
 -G fmt  Set source label format to fmt       as config
 -I mlf  Load master label file mlf
 -S f    Set script file to f                 none
 -T N    Set trace flags to N                 0
 -V      Print version information            off
```

Note that HTK has a non-standard way of asking for command line help, you don't use -h or --help, just the command with no options. It should give you an idea if you can go ahead and make install.

If you still get errors, post back.